# How to Update Csv File

Tags: apex, attachment

So, Basically I am able to insert a csv file in notes & attachment in its parent account but I want to update particular csv file without creating new csv. Can we do it. If yes Please help me because when i update its gives me error.

Comment: what have you tried? what part of it isn't working? please edit your question with exact details on what you're stuck on

Answer (score 1):

You need to explain the problem in greater detail. Without knowing what error you faced, it is difficult to give an accurate answer. But it is possible to upload a new version of the file by following the steps below:

1. Navigate to the 'View All' in the notes & attachment
2. Click the arrow button at the right, and choosing 'Upload New Version'.

[image: Related list in Parent record]
[image: View ALL and upload new version]